# HTML textarea with scroll but prevent editing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, string, textarea

I have text formatted with line breaks. There's more text than will fit vertically, so it scrolls. Fine.

```
const securityMessage = 'Here's my text.\r\nHere's another line and so on.';
```

I need to display the text in a scrolling area on a page, but have a modal with an HTML `textarea` where my users can edit the text.

First I tried using a `textarea`, which works fine but is editable. But setting the control's `readonly` attribute also disallows scrolling,so the user can't preview all the text without opening the modal.

```
<textarea name="secMsg" formControlName="secMsg" cols="30" rows="15" class="form-control h-100" disabled>
</textarea>
```

I have also tried a scrollable DIV with Angular:

```
<div class="secMsg" [innerHTML]="securityMessage"></div>
```

Except that it's not HTML and doesn't recognize the string line breaks.

So, I need to have a plain string with line breaks for my editor `textarea` yet display this text in a scrolling area hat can't be edited.

Comment: Setting the `textarea` to `readonly` shouldn't disable the scrolling. What browser are you using? Maybe you have code somewhere else that's causing this

Comment: You are correct.  On closer inspection someone had added css `pointer-events:none` on items with `[read-only]`.  :-(   Setting it back to "auto" fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div` solution will work, it just needs some CSS to handle the line breaks.

The css `white-space` property is what you are looking for, most likely `white-space: pre-line;` but you can play with the other options to see what suits your use case the best.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: I had no idea.  Thanks.